# It is possible to trigger a non-sibling element with my ID selector using only CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

[This example](https://jsfiddle.net/9ndchpr3/1/) shows in detail... The problem starts with:

```css
.h:hover      { background:red  }
.h:hover ~ td { background:blue }
```

That works fine: the `:hover` event selector *triggers* the following-sibling `td` element. So, we can say that the "`.h:hover` *triggers*  `~ td`"... But, if the `td` element has a backward occurrence, there is no selection.

PS: note that  the `rolspan` in [the example](https://jsfiddle.net/9ndchpr3/1/) causes a "layout with a `td` following-sibling" where structure have a `td` that is not following.

The only possibility is the `#id` selector. So, why does CSS not offer some operator or construction to use `#id` in that constraint?

SUB-QUESTION#1: **is there any pure CSS solution?**

---

(edit) Thanks @TylerH to show that sub-question#1  **is not a duplicate** (!).

The point here is the `#id` selector in a trigger-event context.

Why  CSS3 or CSS4 or "?" standards are not  using `#id` for this kind of application. Are there some standard about CSS events and a better control for manage them?

We know that *there is no "previous sibling" selector*, and this is an understandable problem with parse algorthims.  But *"find `#id`" algorithm* (no matter if next or previous!)  is so simple and so fast, there are no "parse problem" to adopt `#id` in a kind of "trigger selector".

SUB-QUESTION#2: **there are a standardization iniciative ([at CSS WG?](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work))  to do some workaround to the problem, *using `#id` as triggered selector*?**

---

#### PS

The [HTML `label` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL) and `for` attibute   deal with similar problem.  A `<label for="for">` not need Javascript to triggers (by click event) its correspondent `<input type="checkbox" id="for">` checked... So,  we can imagine an *on-mouse-over* correspondent event triggering in the same way,

```css
label#from1:hover <OPERATOR> #for1 { ...do something... }
```

at a typical HTML form like this,

```html
<div id="for1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="mycheck"/>
    <span></span>
</div><!-- tag input BEFORE tag label-->
<label id="from1" for="mycheck">Label for my styled "checkbox"</label>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector

You need javascript.

Comment: CSS has no concept of triggers or events. `.h:hover` doesn't "trigger" the `~ td`, the `td` matches whenever there is a `.h` sibling which is hovered. As for the "for" attribute, the FPWD of Selectors 4 had an idref combinator, but that has been removed from the latest ED. From what I can tell, what you've added to this question should exist as a separate question instead, but it's very unclear to me what is being asked.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock, very welcome your knowledge about CSS. The sub-question#2 is about CSS's "new technologies and trends"... The objective if to check the *big picture* with people like you that have better knowledge, and the point is to understand  **"why [CSS WG](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work) was so careless?"**. We can imagine  dozens of applications for that kind of "simple id trigger selector" (see my explanation about `.label:hover <OPERATOR> #for`).

Comment: @BoltClock, about your citation of [FPWD of Selectors 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#idref-combinators), now I see what you say... May be the  proposal can be to another direction, like the `A <exists> B`, that is a "if A exists them selects B" operator. The `<exist>` can works as previous-sibling-selector when B is an #id. PS: I edited the question text with a better example in the PS section.

Comment: I  found a good answer for sub-question#2! see [Selectors Level 4, sec.4.4. The Relational Pseudo-class `:has()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#relational).  So the key selector for my PS-example is **`body:has(#from1:hover) #for1`**     See [lists.w3.org](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Feb/0555.html).

Comment: @PeterKrauss Yes, just know that, as of now, the `:has()` pseudo-selector is not planned to be included in the fast profile, meaning it **won't** be usable in CSS, only through the DOM via JavaScript or similar languages.

Answer (score 3):

The `~` selector is called the "general sibling" selector. This means it can only be used to select *siblings* of the appropriate element. In your case, the `#c21` element does not have any siblings (brothers or sisters).

What you are asking for cannot be done with pure CSS, because it requires a parent selector (something like `:has()` from CSS Selectors Level 4). By "parent selector", I mean the ability to move backward up the DOM to an ancestor element, so that you can then move to the *ancestor's* sibling, and then to the *ancestor's sibling's child* element.

Think of it this way: the working selector is a boy selecting his sister. That is OK in CSS-land. However, the not-working selector is a boy trying to select his cousin. This is *not* OK in CSS-land, because it requires a *parent selector*. The boy would need to first select his parent, then his parent's brother, and then this parent's brother's son.

The fact that it is an ID rather than a class is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, I edited also my question. Now there are a sub-question#2, that is the "100% not duplicated question", and I was reopening the question.
Your answer to the sub-question#1 is perfect (!). I see that you have some knowledge about CSS4... Can we discuss also  the sub-question#2?

Comment: @PeterKrauss It's probably best for you to ask in the HTML/CSS/Web Design chatroom on Stack Overflow, which I frequent. If I'm not there when you join/ask, just ping me and I will respond when I can.

Comment: Thanks @TylerH (!). I am testing the HTML chatroom (nobody there now)... But I found my answer to sub-question#2, see my comment up at the question.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Great! If you found this answer solved your initial question, remember to select the checkmark to the left of it so that others know of its usefulness.